# Python QP Optimizer sum of quadratic objectives

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, compiler-optimization, quadratic-programming

*I am not sure if I should ask my question here or in maths/cross-validated webpage.*

I am looking for efficient optimizer in python for quadratic programming that it is in the form:

minimize sum_{i=0}^n f_i(x) subject to linear constraints. Each f_i is a quadratic function itself (actually the Q matrix is identity) for all i.

My main issue is with efficiency (time, usually space comes with sparse matrices), for scipy it takes ages as I had to define objective function manually as the sum of n such quadratics. For cplex I couldn't manage to write my problem.

Note: The subproblems are not independent - they are constrained by common matrix.

Comment: I am surprised by the statement "For cplex I couldn't manage to write my problem". Cplex is a very capable QP solver, so I suggest to reconsider. I am not aware of any QP problems that can not be expressed for use with Cplex. For another easy way to express QP problems consider CVXPY (with an appropriate QP solver).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am new to Cplex and I would appreciate which solver should I use in this case and I will dive more into it.

Comment: Actually CVXPY can talk to Cplex.

Comment: I should add that CVXPY is not suited for all models (it cannot express high-dimensional variables).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen can cplex express high-dim variables?

Comment: Absolutely. As I said before, I am not aware of any QP problems that can not be expressed for use with Cplex.